# AdBlock extension in TorBrowser using a lot of CPU power

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, mac, browsers

I upgraded my TorBrowser to 11.0.1, and started noticing that the CPU in my machine is now doing a lot of work when I open TorBrowser.  CPU load of 140-150% is reported used on TorBrowser (a CPU with 4 cores, so max is 400%), even without visiting a single page.  I have the AdBlockPlus extension installed, and noticed that when I disable it the CPU usage is back to low levels.  Does anyone know if the high CPU usage of AdBlockPlus is a bug or a feature, or what in it is causing the high CPU usage?  I would like to block ads, but don't want the fan on my computer to kick in all the time.

Comment: Not an answer, but have you tried other ad blockers such a Ublock Origin? Also, adding an ad blocker kind of defeats the purpose of using Tor browser because it gives you a more unique fingerprint than the default configuration